# Windows 7 does not copy files over network

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, batch

I use a batch to backup files over my network with robocopy. 
This worked fine until now. Whenever I try to retrieve files from another machine now (Windows 7 64 Pro) it justs sits there doing nothing and it takes a long time to even copy a bunch of small files.

I tested the same using Windows explorer. It calculates for about five minutes, copies a small PDF and does it over again. The remaining time is about 3 hours. This is certainly not normal. 
So it basically stops and resumes, recalculates the time and it takes very long.

Host is a Windows 10 64 Pro and there is no anti-virus on the other machine.

There is no problem with internal copying on the remote machine, only when dealing with network copying.

Could this be a problem with a recent Windows 7 update?

Comment: Has the type or amount of data changed any? Has it always been a bunch of small files? This question has been answered a few times here for why small files take longer to copy or whatever.

Comment: Windows Explorer time estimations are meaningless. Test for a problematic installed product by booting into Safe Mode with Networking ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode)).

Comment: "This worked fine until now." So what changed? Windows 7 update is mentioned, but anything else? Router? Electrical noise? Change of location?

Comment: The type or amount of data has not changed. It has always been small files that I copy.

Comment: I tried to boot into safe mode with networking, but now I cannot connect the network share from my Windows 10. I don´t see it. Mapping the drive manually does not work either. Any ideas regarding this?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine until now. Nothing really changed as far as I know. Windows 7 update just came up in my mind. Its just a guess. The PC receives normal regular updates automatically. Router is the same and that also applies to location. Nothing changed there.